# How do i count the number of observations from 2 columns where the variables cannot be separated from one another

Tags: r

I have a data frame of 222 observations and 2 variables: **landslide_z_prediction** and **y** (occurrences)

**landslide_z_prediction** takes values from 0 to 1 while **ytest** takes on integers 0 or 1.

my task is to find out how many of the predicted positives/negatives were predicted correctly.

- if z < 0.5 --> predicted negative
- if z > 0.5 --> predicted positive
- if y = 0 --> observed negative
- if y = 1 --> observed positive

The scenarios are:

a) if z < 0.5 and y = 0 --> prediction is correct

b) if z <0.5 and y = 1 --> prediction is wrong

c) if z > 0.5 and y = 1 --> prediction is correct

d) if z > 0.5 and y = 0 --> prediction is wrong

I have placed my 222 observations in a data.frame format

```
combined_predicitons <- data.frame(landslide_z_predicted, ytest)
```

How am I able to extract out the number of occurrences of each scenarios?

Comment: Plase, provide a sample of the data that you want to analyze. In order to understand the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hy,

I found one solution for your problem with the `dplyr` package. Here is the code:

```
library(dplyr)

# generate sample data
df <- data.frame(landslide_z_predicted=runif(75), y=sample(c(0, 1), 75, replace=T))

# add is_correct and case variables to the data frame
df <- df %>%
  mutate(is_correct = case_when((landslide_z_predicted < 0.5) & !y ~ TRUE,
                                (landslide_z_predicted >= 0.5) & y ~ TRUE,
                                TRUE ~ FALSE)) %>%
 mutate(case = case_when((landslide_z_predicted < 0.5) & !y & is_correct ~ "case_01",
                          (landslide_z_predicted < 0.5) & y & !is_correct ~ "case_02",
                          (landslide_z_predicted >= 0.5) & y & is_correct ~ "case_03",
                          (landslide_z_predicted >= 0.5) & !y & !is_correct ~ "case_04"))

# count the occurrences of the cases
df %>% select(case) %>% group_by(case) %>% summarize(count=n())
```

First I generate a variable called `is_correct`. This is True/False if the prediction was correct or not. In the second mutate I list all your cases from your question and name them "case_01", "case_02" ,... With that in hand I can group the data frame by the cases and count the occurrences.

Comment: i have edited the length of my landslide_z_predicted from 75 to 222. but the second half of the code does not run...

Comment: Would be nice if you show your code. I can’t guess what you have done exactly. Becuase the code above did work for all numbers of observations. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a make a **[confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix)**.

In order to make it I can suggest you this:

**1 -** Change z values into 1 or 0 according with your **threshold**:

Since your **threshold** is at 0.5 you could use `round`.

```
combined_predicitons$landslide_z_predicted_dicotomy = round(combined_predicitons$landslide_z_predicted)
```

Otherwise, use `ifelse`, if the value predicted is over the **threshold**, it will output a value of 1, 0 otherwise.

```
threshold = 0.5    
combined_predicitons$landslide_z_predicted_dicotomy = ifelse(combined_predicitons$landslide_z_predicted >= threshold, 1, 0)
```

**2 -** Create the `table`

```
table(combined_predicitons$y, combined_predicitons$landslide_z_predicted_dicotomy)
```

With this, you'll have the number of ocurrences of each scenario.

Comment: i am getting an error that says Error in table(combined_predicitons$y, combined_predicitons$landslide_z_predicted_dicotomy) : all arguments must have the same length. I changed the number of variables from 75 to 222.

Comment: This problems come that length(combined_predicitons$y), and length(combined_predicitons$landslide_z_predicted_dicotomy) are different. And they shouldn't. {Unless class(combined_predicitons$landslide_z_predicted) is not "numeric" or is not the same size as y}

I found that there was an extra space at my second chunk of code. But this shouldn't be the problem.

I re-runned the code and I have no errors.

Check with class(combined_predicitons$y), class(combined_predicitons$landslide_z_predicted) and class(combined_predicitons$landslide_z_predicted_dicotomy) that they're all numeric.

Comment: I assume that when you say "I changed the number of variables from 75 to 222" it's about the number of rows.

Check that if there are more rows, each row has y and landslide_z_predicted values.